# Blade valor default laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.2

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<strong class="primary-font">Complemento</strong>
<p>{{ $produto->complemento or 'Esta produto não tem complemento' }}</p>
```

Preciso que caso o valor $produto->complemento esteja em branco, o sistema exibir o texto 'Esta produto não tem complemento', porém dessa forma não está funcionando.

Comment: Considere dar uma olhadinha na minha resposta. Creio que é um jeito que torna as coisas mais fáceis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso a variável exista mas esteja vazia ('') pode fazer o seguinte:

```
{{($produto->complemento != '') ? $produto->complemento : 'Este produto não tem complemento'}}
```

Ou:

```
{{(trim($produto->complemento) != '') ? $produto->complemento : 'Este produto não tem complemento'}}
```

O `or` é 'traduzido' pelo Laravel como:

```
if(isset($var)) {
    echo $var;
}
...
```

Ora isto quer dizer que se a `$var` está declarada, mesmo que seja uma string vazia, ele vai fazer sempre o echo dessa `$var`. Temos de fazer nós 'manualmente' (que eu saiba não existe em blade esta verificação built-in) a condição

Comment: tbm acabei fazendo dessa forma quando passei por isso... Mas pq o tal do **or** não funciona?

Comment: É porque ela existe. Vou editar a pergunta com a explicação @RaylanSoares

Comment: é, pelo que entendi isso meio que da um retorno booleano, e não o valor do campo como parece que seria né, pois quando faço assim ele retorna "1" se existir se não me engano

Comment: Exato em php nativo (que é em que Laravel vai converter isto) é equivalente a `echo ($produto->complemento != '') ? $produto->complemento : 'Este pro...';` . pode até testar: `<?php echo ($produto->complemento != '') ? $produto->complemento : 'Este pro...'; ?>` . Por isso sim, é isso mesmo, o retorno de `($produto->complemento != '')` é `true` ou `false` (booleano)

Comment: Entendi, só acho q ele poderia retornar logo o valor real da variável direto, facilitaria bastante, mas obrigado pelo esclarecimento @Miguel

Comment: O valor real da variável no problema que se pôs é `""`, uma string vazia @RaylanSoares

Comment: ah sim, agr caiu a ficha kkk

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a solução apresentada e marcada como aceita vai gerar muito código desnecessário se você quiser fazer isso em várias linhas.

Ao invés disso, porque não usar o operador `?:` do PHP? Creio que além de melhorar o entendimento do código, você vai ter menos trabalho.

Ao invés de fazer assim:

```
{{ ($produto->complemento != '') ? $produto->complemento : 'Este produto não tem complemento' }}
```

É mais fácil fazer isso:

```
{{ $produto->complemento ?: 'Este produto não tem complemento' }}
```

Se precisar utilizar o `trim`, você pode fazer assim também:

```
{{ trim($produto->complemento) ?: 'Este produto não tem complemento' }}
```

Veja um exemplo, usando `PHP`, no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/DmmRuT)

Answer (score -1):

No Laravel 5.0 ou superior não se usa mais `{{ }}` e sim `{!! !!}`

```
{!! $produto->complemento or 'Esta produto não tem complemento' !!}
```

Comment: Então, mas fui buscar direto na documentação do 5.2 e lá tinha isso, mas aqui não funcionou nem dessa forma nem da outra

Comment: Tem valor na coluna ? Certeza ?

Comment: Sim, meu banco tem o campo complemento, porém uma pessoa pode cadastrar um produto sem complemento. Quando o usuário clica em detalhes do produto o sistema chama a função detalhes passando o id na função: 
public function detalhes($id) 
{ 
    $igreja = Igreja::find($id); 
    return view('admin/igrejas/detalhes')->with('igreja', $igreja); 
}

que é usado por o código

<strong class="primary-font">Complemento</strong>
                    <p>{{ $igreja->complemento or 'Esta igreja não tem complemento' }}</p>
porém nada acontece